# How to list all active usernames with active session in Apache Tomcat server and Glassfish Server

Tags: session, tomcat, glassfish

For my requirement I need to have list of all active username with active session in Apache Tomcat server & Glassfish server.

Comment: Do you need to do this within the JVM/Tomcat or from outside? Are you in a clustered environment and need usernames from all servers, or just a single one?

Comment: There is one tomcat server and one glassfish server. In tomcat server there is only one domain and single application is running and In glassfish server there are total 6 domains and in each domain there are different applications running. I have to collect active usernames from each domain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about GlassFish, but you can script Tomcat to do it, especially if you have an object in the user's session that contains their username. In my session, I have a "user" object which can be used for this.

Here's the recipe:

1. Install Tomcat's `manager` web application and configure it for proper authentication
2. Use a script like the following:

```sh
for sessionid in `wget -qO - 'http://username:password@host:port/manager/jmxproxy?invoke=Catalina:type=Manager,context=/contextName,host=localhost&op=listSessionIds' \
  | sed -e "s/ /\n/g" -e 's/.*returned://'`
do
    response=`wget -qO - "http://username:password@host:port/manager/jmxproxy?invoke=Catalina:type=Manager,context=/contextName,host=localhost&op=getSessionAttribute&ps=$sessionid,user" 2>/dev/null`

    #echo "$response"

    if [ `expr "$response" : "^OK"` ] ; then
      user=`expr "$response" : ".*\(User.*\)"`
      if [ "$user" ] ; then
        echo "$sessionid: $user"
      else if [ "$VERBOSE" ] ; then
        echo "$sessionid: [ no authenticated user ]"
      fi fi
    else
      echo "[error]: $response"
    fi
done
```

<s>Hmm... back-quotes are not looking good up there. Let me do some reading on how to make that code snippet readable and I'll update this answer. Both of the `wget` commands should have backtics around them, and the first one should have the close-backtick after the `returned://'` string.</s>